# $\sum a_n^2 $-convergent $\Rightarrow? \sum\frac{|a_n|}{n} -$ convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is $\sum\frac{|a_n|}{n}$ convergent , while  $\sum a_n^2$ is convergent?

I tried from Cauchy definition but failed.

How can it be done some common way?

$\sum a_n^2 $-convergent $\Rightarrow?  \sum\frac{|a_n|}{n} -$ convergent

Comment: You may as well assume $a_n$ non-negative

Comment: I assume that you are asking (since this seems the most reasonable interpretation) that $\sum_{n} a_n^2$ converging $\implies \sum_{n} \frac{a_n}{n}$ converges. This follows from the fact that $\sum_{n}2\frac{a_n}{n} \le \sum_{n} a_n^2 + \frac{1}{n^2}$, since the inequality holds termwise for the two series because $(a_n - \frac{1}{n})^2 \ge 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Your wording is ambiguous, presumably you meant iff? If $\sum_n |a_n|^2$ converges then so does $\sum_n \frac{a_n}{n}$ by the Cauchy Schwarz inequality. The reverse direction is not true. Take $a_n=1/\sqrt{n}$.